# Página em branco requisição API em PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, libcurl

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição para a url:

http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v0/Login/Autenticar?token=XXXX

e a resposta em caso de `token` válido deveria ser `true`.

Já tentei de várias maneiras usando `Curl` e `GuzzleHttp`, todas me retornam uma *blank page*. Testei o `token` no postman e funciona.
Estou na curva de aprendizado da linguagem e gostaria de saber o jeito mais simples e funcional e ver o retorno na página.

Agradeço desde já.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v0/Login/Autenticar");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "?token=XXXX");
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: antes de executar o curl_close, verifique se houve algum erro e exiba o erro na tela. Caso haja, poste aqui por favor. Verificando se tem erro no curl: if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

Comment: já tentou com CURL puro no terminal?

Comment: @LFZiron Ainda continuo recebendo uma página em branco.

Comment: @pmargreff Vendo alguns tutoriais recebo erros, teria alguma diga de fazer a requisição post via terminal? 
ERRO:"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI". Acho que pode estar havendo algum erro quanto aos dados e a URL raiz que é "http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v0/", 
sabe me dizer o que é parâmetro, dados e como passá-los?

Comment: @LetíciaCastroPereira já tentou utilizar   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

Comment: @LFZiron Já havia tentando antes, tentei novamente e com o mesmo resultado.